# Migration problem from MS Graph SDK 4 to SDK 5

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to migrate MS Graph SDK 4 to the latest version 5. I cannot figure out the correct way of writing this v4 working statement in v5.

```
GraphServiceClient client = new(...);
WorkbookRange d = await client
   .Me.Drive
   .Items[bookId]
   .Workbook
   .Worksheets[tabId]
   .Range("A1:XX1")
   .Request()
   .GetAsync(cancellation)
   .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Just upgraded our solution too. Was a lot of stuff and the biggest headache is really the re-write of the one drive access. The best source for common problems on upgrade are listed in the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Drives` to access `Items` and `Workbook`:

```
var myDrive = await client.Me.Drive.GetAsync();
var workbookRange = await client.Drives[myDrive.Id].Items[bookId].Workbook.Worksheets[tabId].RangeWithAddress("A1:XX1").GetAsync(cancellationToken: cancellation);
```

or this should also work

```
var workbookRange = await client.Drives["Me"].Items[bookId].Workbook.Worksheets[tabId].RangeWithAddress("A1:XX1").GetAsync(cancellationToken: cancellation);
```